# How to install cheerio in react-native?

Tags: react-native, cheerio

I have been trying to use cheerio in React-native, but none of the solutions provided in https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1058 worked. How do you add Cheerio to React-native?

Comment: It's an npm package, am not sur it's possible without running `node something`

Comment: i have tried 1)$ npm i cheerio@0.22.0 $ npm i events stream buffer 2)$ npm i cheerio-without-node-native@0.20.2 both aren't working